# Computational efficiency: 0 vs. false (or true)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, boolean

I was looking through the `ui-bootstrap.js` (from the Angular seed, I believe) after reading some stuff on `transclusion` in directives. I noticed they use:

```
transclude: !0
```

as opposed to most of the documentation I've seen which declares it:

```
transclude: true
```

Is there some efficiency gained with using the numerical vs. lexical declaration of a boolean value (particularly in Javascript)? Maybe this is occuring after minification, which would sort of answer my former question, but I'm still curious as to why that would-be/is.

Comment: It's two bytes shorter. Two bytes less on the wire. Is it worth it? Well, to me `!0` is as `true` as `true`, but I've got an old asleep C programmer inside me.

Comment: That would answer it. How did I not even think of that? :(

Comment: ...and as to the computational efficiency of the two, you'd have to do a benchmark to compare them. Though I imagine if the engine isn't optimized for it, since `!0` performs a comparison to equate true while `true` needs no comparison, `true` should be faster. Although the difference in just one call should hardly be noticable.

Comment: @Jan the parser could very well collapse `!0` into `true`, and though that would take a tiny amount of time it would only happen when the source code was parsed. In any case saving a quarter microsecond here and there is very unlikely to make any difference to anything.

Comment: And @Jan I don't intend to be confrontational, I'm agreeing with you and just emphasizing that the difference is probably so tiny it's not worth worrying about at all.

Comment: @Pointy yes that's what I meant by "if the (Javascript) engine isn't optimized for it" (maybe I should have clarified which engine I meant to begin with). And as I said, even if it wasn't optimized for it, it should hardly make a noticable difference (even when benchmarking) unless you make a few hundred thousand calls, maybe. So we agree completely. :) I just wanted to point out that the two are *possibly* different (although insiginificantly) and if they *are* treated differently, `!0` should be slower.